# textBox items copy to different textBoxes

Tags: c#, loops, textbox

I want to perform a task in one of my project

i want to transfer items in a textBox into different textBoxes.that i can achieve by this

```
string[] values = textBox1.Text.Split('#');
textBox2.Text = values[0];
textBox3.Text = values[1];
textBox4.Text = values[2];
textBox5.Text = values[3];
textBox6.Text = values[4];
```

**what i want is when 5 items are copied in 5 different textboxes. those 5 items must be deleted from the origin textbox.**

*OR*

**suppose i got 10 items in a textbox called textBox1 splitted by #.

eg:a#b#c#d#e#f#g#h#i#j

Now with a button click named button1

following event occurs

a in textBox2/b in textBox3/c in textBox4/d in textBox5/e in textBox6

-Now when i click the button1 again

i want the 5 items which are left in textBox1 must be like this

f in textBox2/g in textBox3/h in textBox4/i in textBox5/j in textBox6

Answer (score 1):

I would start writing a method that tries to split your string taking a value to limit the amount of splitted strings to return. The same method should delete, from the input string the parts splitted and return both the array with the splitted strings and the remainder of the original string.

```
string[] SplitWithLimit(ref string test, int limit)
{
    int count=0;
    int pos=-1;

    // Try to find the position of the # at the limit count
    while((pos = test.IndexOf('#', pos+1)) != -1)
    {
        count++;
        if(count == limit)
            break;
    }

    string toSplit;
    if(pos != -1)
    {
        // Take the left part of the string to be splitted
        // till the position of the char at limit boundary
        toSplit = test.Substring(0, pos);
        test = test.Substring(pos+1);
    }
    else
    {
        // If there are less # than required, take all the string
        toSplit = test;
        test = "";
    }
    // Now split only the required part   
    string[] parts = toSplit.Split(new char[] {'#'}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    return parts;
}
```

Now it is just a matter of handling the results of this operation setting the original textbox with the remainder and the receiving textbox with the splitted array

```
TextBox2.Text =string.Empty;
TextBox3.Text =string.Empty;
TextBox4.Text =string.Empty;
TextBox5.Text =string.Empty;
TextBox6.Text =string.Empty;

string test = TextBox1.Text; //"a#b#c#d#e#f#g#h#j"
string[] parts = SplitWithLimit(ref test, 5);
if(parts.Length > 0)
    TextBox2.Text = parts[0];
if(parts.Length > 1)
    TextBox3.Text = parts[1];
if(parts.Length > 2)
    TextBox4.Text = parts[2];
if(parts.Length > 3)
    TextBox5.Text = parts[3];
if(parts.Length > 4)
    TextBox6.Text = parts[4];

TextBox1.Text = test;
```

Comment: sir it throws following error ((Index was outside the bounds of the array.)) in line ((textBox2.Text = parts[0];))

Comment: Got it, change the >= to >, fixing now

Comment: @HassanNisar well, the code already clears the receiving textboxes before starting the op.

Answer (score 0):

For deleting from `Origin TextBox` use: (Just example)

```
TextBox1.Text = TextBox1.Text.Substring(10);
```

Something like that if you are sure 5 items:

```
 private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {  
       string[] values = textBox1.Text.Split('#');

        if (values.Length >= 5)
        {
            textBox2.Text = values[0];
            textBox3.Text = values[1];
            textBox4.Text = values[2];
            textBox5.Text = values[3];
            textBox6.Text = values[4];

            //change the destination
             if (values.Length == 5)
                textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Substring(9); 
            else if (values.Length > 5)
                textBox1.Text = textBox1.Text.Substring(10); 
        }
  }
```

Comment: can you please elaborate.when 5 items are picked from textBox1 to various text Boxes.Those 5 items must be deleted from textBox1.

Comment: @Dr.Zeus have you tried above code for fixed 5 items?

Comment: sir your code splits one item into two parts randomly.eg if item is c++ it sends c to textbox2 ++ to textbox3

Comment: ya sure sir i entered gwevkfmioyxycr#dmgehnhwbnexu#qwgsrpfwmwdotwqcr#qxksihpdhreeqfggrwemrsg#ryqrflxujeejtdefpvsxegfoe#gfgynwwxjexpks#rkewcilmwtgagwhfsvffcyrbf#kxgpgvwryvfxebvb#mepdrcjfexe#creohkjdd#rrffauurslfkefhkkrrofdwea#fxwjwhdchrrvf#skgchwygaseulpqfffdxegesqvt#feuecwetfscmibjwnfqfehdgrhb#isisokcrukpyeamugnaqf#rvpyquljfbhegqaskorgmfrtp#esevwfhtkungflcixstfvhsgkw#pkdiwcgwfdsqjlggkgmnvsc#

Answer (score 0):

Try this, previous values will be automatically deleted once user clicks the button and it gets replaced by new one

```
    int noOfTimesClicked=0;

    private void FillTextBoxes()
    {
          string[] values = textBox1.Text.Split('#');
          textBox2.Text = values[noOfTimesClicked] != null ? values[noOfTimesClicked] : "";
          textBox3.Text = values[(noOfTimesClicked) + 1] != null ? values[(noOfTimesClicked) + 1] : "";
          textBox4.Text = values[(noOfTimesClicked) + 2] != null ? values[(noOfTimesClicked) + 2] : "";
          textBox5.Text = values[(noOfTimesClicked) + 3] != null ? values[(noOfTimesClicked) + 3] : "";
          textBox6.Text = values[(noOfTimesClicked) + 4] != null ? values[(noOfTimesClicked) + 4]:"";
          noOfTimesClicked = noOfTimesClicked + 5;
    }
```

Hope this helps you :)

Comment: sorry sir but this not helping me out.:(